# Thumbnails for multiple links in same Facebook post

Tags: facebook

Can I get multiple thumbnails for multiple links referenced in a Facebook post? Usually, the thumbnail is generated for the first link, but not for the second onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the one thumbnail per post.  However, you can post the second link as a comment, and that will generate a preview with a thumbnail in the comment.

You'll have less control over the thumbnail in the comment.  If you have multiple images on the webpage, Facebook will choose which one to display (I'm not certain how it decides) rather than letting you scroll through the images to choose one yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can try the multiple links in single fb post, through 3 ways:

1. When you paste the link at fb, by default it provides the preview for your post, and it allows you to upload images (up to five)

> By that time (before to publish the post) facebook allows you to update the links also, so five different images and five different links in a single post.

2. And, it allows you to work on the same concept through the "Share a Photo or Video" option by selecting "Create a Photo/Video Carousel"
3. And for sometimes facebook itself provides the images in the article when you paste the URL in the space.

> The third option happens on the priority basis, hence better to opt
>   the first and second options while you want to try to post the
>   different thumbnails with different links.